# Javascript - MIN_VALUE vs MIN_SAFE_INTEGER vs -Infinity

Tags: javascript, numbers

I recently ran into an error where I did this expression:

```
Math.max(Number.MIN_VALUE, 0)
// returns 5e-324
```

I'm not quite sure how it returned this value, so I tried inverting the expression to see what would happen:

```
Math.min(Number.MAX_VALUE, 0)
// returns 0
```

This works fine however..

The way I fixed the first expression is by doing this:

```
Math.max(Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER, 0)
// returns 0
```

**A few questions:**

1. Why does taking the MAX of `Number.MIN_VALUE` and zero equal 5e-324?
2. If we have `Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER` should we always use this or is there a use case for `Number.MIN_VALUE`?
3. If I am just using MIN/MAX values as an initial state (that will for sure be overwritten on the first comparison), should I use `-Inifinity / Infinity` instead?

Comment: For question **1)**, It is because [Number.MIN_VALUE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MIN_VALUE) > 0.

Comment: `Number.MIN_VALUE` is the smallest *positive* number. So of course it's greater than zero, if only by a tiny amount.

Comment: Hmm that seems odd compared to other languages, I think. Is there a use case for using a number so close to zero, but not using zero itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does taking the MAX of Number.MIN_VALUE and zero equal 5e-324

Because `Math.MIN_VALUE` is not the lowest negative value. Its minimum positive value. So all the positive values are greater than `0` that's why it return `5e-324` instead of `0`

> If we have Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER should we always use this or is there a use case for Number.MIN_VALUE?

I can't think of any use case for `Number.MIN_VALUE` because its not safe. It can create wrong calculations in code.

> If I am just using MIN/MAX values as an initial state (that will for sure be overwritten on the first comparison), should I use -Inifinity / Infinity instead

It completely depends upon the purpose of the code.